# Targeting Section Element in CSS

Tags: css

can you please let me know how to target a `section` element with a specific id like `#dress` in CSS3?
Here is the code which I have:

```
<section id="dress">
 <p> Lorem Ipsum.................................. of Lorem Ipsum.<>
</section>
```

and the style:

```
section #dress{
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
```

but it is not working

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The space, , is the [Descendant selector](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/selector.html#descendant-selectors).  The selector that you want is `section#dress`.

However, I think that this selector is not easy to maintain.  Instead, it would be better to use `#dress` so that you can select the element irrespective of its type.

As an addendum to that, there is a suggestion out there that says that you should stick to classes pretty much exclusively for selectors in CSS because of the specificity rules that are applied to IDs.  For example, say you had to change the styles for this `#dress` at a later date:

```
#dress {
    background-color: #cdcdcd;
}
.label-list {
    background-color: #dcdcdc;
}
```

Now if you had `<section id="dress" class="label-list">`, the background would still be `#cdcdcd` even though `.label-list` follows in the cascade.  You may want to stick to classes for styles.  This is just a suggestion, though, and not a hard rule.

Comment: Thanks Explosion Pills it works now, I need to have 12 minutes to accept this answer as correct one, however!